# Error in Threading SARIMAX model

Tags: python, parallel-processing, arima

I am using threading library for the first time inorder to speed up the training time of my SARIMAX model. But the code keeps failing with the following error

```
Bad direction in the line search; refresh the lbfgs memory and restart the iteration.
This problem is unconstrained.
This problem is unconstrained.
This problem is unconstrained.
```

Following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt
from threading import Thread

def process_id(ndata):
   train = ndata[0:-7]
   test = ndata[len(train):]
   try:
       model = smt.SARIMAX(train.asfreq(freq='1d'), exog=None, order=(0, 1, 1), seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 7)).fit()
       pred = model.get_forecast(len(test))
       fcst = pred.predicted_mean
       fcst.index = test.index
       mapelist = []
       for i in range(len(fcst)):
            mapelist.insert(i, (np.absolute(test[i] - fcst[i])) / test[i])
       mape = np.mean(mapelist) * 100
       print(mape)
    except:
       mape = 0
       pass
return mape

def process_range(ndata, store=None):
   if store is None:
      store = {}
   for id in ndata:
      store[id] = process_id(ndata[id])
   return store


def threaded_process_range(nthreads,ndata):
    store = {}
    threads = []
    # create the threads
    k = 0
    tk = ndata.columns
    for i in range(nthreads):
        dk  = tk[k:len(tk)/nthreads+k]
        k = k+len(tk)/nthreads
        t = Thread(target=process_range, args=(ndata[dk],store))
        threads.append(t)
    [ t.start() for t in threads ]
    [ t.join() for t in threads ]
    return store

outdata = threaded_process_range(4,ndata)
```

Few things I would like to mention:

- Data is daily stock time series in a dataframe
- Threading works for ARIMA model
- SARIMAX model works when done in a for loop

Any insights would be highly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error with lbfgs, I'm not sure why lbfgs fails to do gradient evaluations, but I tried changing the optimizer. You can try this too, choose among any of these optimizers

’newton’ for Newton-Raphson, ‘nm’ for Nelder-Mead

’bfgs’ for Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno (BFGS)

’lbfgs’ for limited-memory BFGS with optional box constraints

’powell’ for modified Powell’s method

’cg’ for conjugate gradient

’ncg’ for Newton-conjugate gradient

’basinhopping’ for global basin-hopping solver

change this in your code

`model = smt.SARIMAX(train.asfreq(freq='1d'), exog=None, order=(0, 1, 1), seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 7)).fit(method='cg')`

It's an old question but still I'm answering it in case someone in future faces the same problem.